# 2 version of Cmake, needs to remove one

Tags: 18.04, software-uninstall, cmake

I'm having an issue with Cmake.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed the newest version of Cmake (3.18.0).
Since I'm kind of new to Linux in general, I thought installing new version will override the last version and simply update it, unfortunately I was wrong.
Now sometimes when I try to set minimum version to above 3.10, I'm getting the follwing error:

```
CMake 3.17 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.10.2
```

It's obviously that I need to remove the older version, but I'm not sure how to remove a specific version, whenever I try to locate the Cmake folder, the directory is:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake
```

Which isn't the directory, specifically not the directory that I need (3.10.2 one).

How can I remove specific version of Cmake?
Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
As suggested on the comment below, the output of `which -a cmake`:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
```

The Cmake at `/usr/bin/cmake` is the bad version (3.10.2).

Comment: The version that is executed will depend on the order of locations in your `PATH`. If you want to use a specific version you can always use its full path ex. `/usr/bin/cmake ..`

Comment: @steeldriver I don't want to specify every time, I want the newest version to always be used as default

Comment: How you remove something depends entirely upon how you installed it. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260844/edit) to show the complete output of `which -a cmake`

Comment: @user535733 edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was a issue with both versions, I thought the best plan of action was to simply remove all version and install the one I wanted.
But after running `sudo apt-get remove cmake` , I've noticed the the only version removed was the "bad" version (3.10.2).
And now everything is running as it should.